# Catch event of activation of the plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

Could you tell me why when I activate the plugin, error log is empty?
I just want to catch the event of activation of the plugin (to create tables).

```
class International_Law {

    public static function init_actions() {     
        register_activation_hook( $file = __FILE__, 
                                  $callback = array( 'International_Law' , 'activate' ) );
    }   
    

    
    public static function activate(){
        error_log("activate");
    }
}

add_action( $hook_name =  'init', 
            $callback = array( 'International_Law', 'init_actions' ) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was that one can’t call register_activation_hook() inside a function hooked to the 'init'.

Doc: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_activation_hook/#more-information